# Matplotlib re-ordering y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Attempting to make a simple 2D matplotlib plot, but it's re-ordering the y-axis labels to keep the graph linear. How can I avoid this?

**Code:**

```py
data = np.array([
    ['Jun 1', 1.2, 0.2],
    ['Jun 2', 1.3, 1.2],
    ['Jun 3', 1.4, 0.9],
    ['Jun 4', 1.1, 0.5],
    ['Jun 5', 1.6, 1.2],
    ['Jun 6', 2.2, 0.2],
    ['Jun 7', 3.4, 1.6]
])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'income', 'spent'])
plt.plot(df['income'])
```

[image]

I'd just like a normal graph:
X axis: index
Y axis: df.income (where the visual plot range is auto-calculated)

The same issue with the scatterplot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your types. When numpy sees a string, it assumes everything in the array to be an object. So your income and spent data is actually text if you dig into the dtypes. Reconvert them before plotting:

```
data = np.array([
    ['Jun 1', 1.2, 0.2],
    ['Jun 2', 1.3, 1.2],
    ['Jun 3', 1.4, 0.9],
    ['Jun 4', 1.1, 0.5],
    ['Jun 5', 1.6, 1.2],
    ['Jun 6', 2.2, 0.2],
    ['Jun 7', 3.4, 1.6]
])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'income', 'spent'])

for c in ['income', 'spent']:
    df[c] = df[c].astype(float)

plt.plot(df['income'])
```

or (better practice):

```
data = [
    ['Jun 1', 1.2, 0.2],
    ['Jun 2', 1.3, 1.2],
    ['Jun 3', 1.4, 0.9],
    ['Jun 4', 1.1, 0.5],
    ['Jun 5', 1.6, 1.2],
    ['Jun 6', 2.2, 0.2],
    ['Jun 7', 3.4, 1.6]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'income', 'spent'])

plt.plot(df['income'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your data types are objects. You can see the data types of your dataframe by using `dataframe.dtypes`.

```
df.dtypes

> date      object
> income    object
> spent     object
> dtype: object
```

What you need is that the column `'income'` be a `float64`, so you can manually set up its data type:

```
df['income'] = df['income'].astype('float64')

> date      object
> income    float64
> spent     object
> dtype: object
```

Now, if you plot the df, you get:

[image: df plot]

You can also set the `date` to be the `x axis` by setting your date column as an index of the dataframe:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
```

[image: df plot with date as index]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the issue for the x-axis, now for the **y-axis** the issue is that when you converted the `np.array` you didn't specify the `dtype` of the array.

if you add this simple line it should work just fine.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([
    ['Jun 1', 1.2, 0.2],
    ['Jun 2', 1.3, 1.2],
    ['Jun 3', 1.4, 0.9],
    ['Jun 4', 1.1, 0.5],
    ['Jun 5', 1.6, 1.2],
    ['Jun 6', 2.2, 0.2],
    ['Jun 7', 3.4, 1.6]
], dtype=object)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'income', 'spent'])

df.plot(x='date', y='income', kind='line')
plt.show()
```

sometimes pandas has problems of understanding the data, the problem was that it was treating the income row as a string.